# magento customer review submit event or other to filter out certain strings

Tags: event-observer, extensions, review

I was browsing a Magento event cheat sheet because I was hoping to find an event: review submit save before ... and capture the title/name/text from the description. And set the review to deleted or dissaproved if certain strings are shown - like "href" or "http"
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

We are currently seeing so much spam in our review forms that a quick check for these two strings would filter out 99% ...

I would be hoping to turn this into a simple extension where keywords in the backend can be separated by commas and these are then looked for in the reviews

Question: is there such an event? and how would I go about capturing the values and check for the *forbidden* words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an event dispatched when saving a review `review_save_before` for example.

Comment: top! Just what I am looking for - and is review_save_before an existing (real) event or just an example

Comment: It actually exists. It is dispatched by this line `Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());` in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave()`. and when saving a review the `_eventPrefix` is `review`.

Comment: And do you think I can cancel or dissaprove the review this way? (Or only exit the function and redirect)

Comment: You can can manage to set `_dataSaveAllowed` on the review model instance then it won't be saved. But unfortunately I don't know how you can set that because it's a protected member and there is no setter for it. You can try with Reflection.

Comment: I was fiddling with this. And suppose we just return the URL with error messages "cannot save illegal characters" the we should also be done ... Gets the job done

Comment: If you're up for it. I came up with a simple solution. Maybe we add a simple JS validation before submit that check for certain text strings ... (mainly http or www) .. maybe even via the validator- and if found cancels submit .. maybe the simplest solution

Comment: @snh_nl You could to a JS validation, but never trust client side validation. Someone can go around it. You need server side validation to be sure it works properly.

Comment: I agree. But I think we are now just hit by robots recognizing Magento forms & entering data, finding the submit button and submitting! ANything out of the ordinary will probably help for now

Comment: Just throwing an exception would probably work, I know it does for aborting add to cart actions. The exception message is displayed in the frontend by JS on that one.